# Titulo de Google charts no aparece

Tags: php, html, jquery

un saludo enorme. Tengo un ligero problema con las graficas (Que a mi parecer son bastante inestables) de Google charts.
Les comento que tengo 3 botones que cada uno hace una funcion con jquery (Solo aparecer y desaparecer 3 graficas) al cargar la pagina aparece como default la primera grafica esa sin problema pero al cambiar el boton a me aparece la grafica sin titulos y los textos de los items igual todo desordenado. Quisiera saber como arreglar ese error. Cabe decir que en consola no aparece ningun error, y en la tabla hasta arriba hay un punto y un parentesis chiquito que anteriormente me a salido en otros errores. 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguna solución que se les ocurra. Puedo pasar el codigo sin problema. 
Dejo el codigo completo desde php.

```
 <?php
       error_reporting(10); 

       require_once "php/conexion.php";

       $conexion=conexion();

       session_start();
       $edat = $_SESSION['user'];

       if ($conexion->connect_error) //verificamos si hubo un error al           
       conectar, recuerden que pusimos el @ para evitarlo
       {
       die('Error de conexión: ' . $conexion->connect_error); //si hay un error 
       termina la aplicación y mostramos el error
       }
       //******************Graficas********************
       $fecha_actual = date('Y-m-d');
       $fecha_desde =  date('Y-m')."-01";
       //comprobacion de contactos de parte de edat
        $contacto_edat = "select * from llenado_formulario where edat = 
       '".$edat."' and fechareg >= '".$fecha_desde."' and fechareg <= 
       '".$fecha_actual."'";
       $edat_result = $conexion->query($contacto_edat);
        $contactos = mysqli_num_rows($edat_result);

       //comprobacion de citas de parte de edat
        $citas_edat = "select * from llenado_formulario where resul_llamada = 
      'CITA' and edat = '".$edat."' and fechareg >= '".$fecha_desde."' and 
      fechareg 
      <= '".$fecha_actual."'";
      $citas_result = $conexion->query($citas_edat);
      $citas = mysqli_num_rows($citas_result);

      //comprobacion de conexion de parte de edat

    $conexion_edat = "select * from llenado_formulario where edat = '".$edat."' 
     and fechareg >= '".$fecha_desde."' and fechareg <= '".$fecha_actual."' and  
     conexion = ('Provisional' or 'Definitiva')";
    $conexion_result = $conexion->query($conexion_edat);
    $conexionr = mysqli_num_rows($conexion_result);

      //****************Consulta metas mensuales***********
      //****************contactos***********
      $meta_m_e = "select * from metas where nombre = '".$edat."'";
       $meta_m_er = $conexion->query($meta_m_e);
      $filam= mysqli_fetch_array ($meta_m_er);
      //****************contactos***********
       $citas_m_e = "select * from metas where nombre = '".$edat."'";
       $citas_m_er = $conexion->query($citas_m_e);
       $filacm= mysqli_fetch_array ($citas_m_er);
       //****************conexion***********
       $conexion_m_e = "select * from metas where nombre = '".$edat."'";
       $conexion_m_er = $conexion->query($conexion_m_e);
       $filacom= mysqli_fetch_array ($conexion_m_er);
         ?>

   //Termina php y empieza html

      <html>
      <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="librerias/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="librerias/alertify/css/alertify.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="librerias/alertify/css/themes/default.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="librerias/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="librerias/datatable/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">

    <script src="librerias/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/funciones.js"></script>
    <script src="librerias/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="librerias/alertify/alertify.js"></script>
    <script src="librerias/datatable/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="librerias/datatable/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
     </head>
      <body>
  <!--Barra de navegacion -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
            <li><a><span class="label label-primary">Bienvenido:  <?php echo $edat ?></span></a></li>
            <input hidden id="edat" value="<?php echo $edat ?>">
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li><a href="metasyres.php">Metas y resultados</a></li> 
            <li><a href="php/logout.php">Salir</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
  <!--Termina barra de navegacion-->
  <!-- metas mensuales -->
  <input hidden id="cmm" value="<?php echo $filam["contactos_meta_mensual"] ?>">
  <input hidden id="cimm" value="<?php echo $filacm["citas_meta_mensual"] ?>"> 
  <input hidden id="comm" value="<?php echo $filacm["conexion_meta_mensual"] ?>"> 
      <!--Meta mensual js-->
      <script type="text/javascript">
        google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

        function drawChart() {
          var cmm = document.getElementById("cmm").value;
          var cimm = document.getElementById("cimm").value;
          var comm = document.getElementById("comm").value;
            cmm = eval(cmm);
            cimm = eval(cimm);
            comm = eval(comm);
          var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Concepto', 'Resultado', 'Meta Mensual'],
            ['Contactos', <?php echo $contactos ?>, cmm],
            ['Citas', <?php echo $citas ?>, cimm],
            ['Conexiones', <?php echo $conexionr ?>, comm]
          ]);
          var options = {
            chart: {
              title: 'Resultados y Metas Mensuales',
              subtitle: 'Correspondientes a la fecha de: <?php echo $fecha_desde ?> a: <?php echo $fecha_actual ?> ',
            },
             width: 750,
              height: 500,
  chartArea: {width: '100%',
             height: '100%'},

              colors: ['#F19D13', '#337ab7']
          };
          var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('1'));

          chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
        }
      </script>
      <!--Meta semestral js-->
      <script type="text/javascript">
        google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart2);

        function drawChart2() {
          var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses', 'Profit'],
            ['2014', 1000, 400, 200],
            ['2015', 1170, 460, 250],
            ['2016', 660, 1120, 300],
            ['2017', 1030, 540, 350]
          ]);

          var options = {
            chart: {
              title: 'Company Performance',
              subtitle: 'Sales, Expenses, and Profit: 2014-2017',
            },

             width: 1000,
              height: 750,
  chartArea: {width: '100%',
             height: '100%'},
          };

          var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('2'));

          chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
        }
      </script>
          <!--Meta anual js-->
      <script type="text/javascript">
        google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart3);

        function drawChart3() {
          var cmm = document.getElementById("cmm").value;
          var cimm = document.getElementById("cimm").value;
          var comm = document.getElementById("comm").value;
            cmm = eval(cmm);
            cimm = eval(cimm);
            comm = eval(comm);
          var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Concepto', 'Resultado', 'Meta anual'],
            ['Contactos', <?php echo $contactos ?>, cmm],
            ['Citas', <?php echo $citas ?>, cimm],
            ['Conexiones', <?php echo $conexionr ?>, comm]
          ]);
          var options = {
            chart: {
              title: 'Resultados y Metas Anuales',
              subtitle: 'Correspondientes a la fecha de: <?php echo $fecha_desde ?> a: <?php echo $fecha_actual ?> ',
            },
             width: 750,
              height: 500,
  chartArea: {width: '100%',
             height: '100%'},

              colors: ['#F19D13', '#337ab7']
          };
          var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('3'));

          chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
        }
      </script>
             <!-- Botones para cambiar el rango de meta, mensual, semestral y anual-->
          <center>
          <button type="button" id="btnmensual" class="btn btn-primary">Mensual</button>
          <button type="button" id="btnsemestral" class="btn btn-primary">Semestral</button>
          <button type="button" id="btnanual" class="btn btn-primary">Anual</button>
              <br>
          </center>
            <!--Grafica metas y resultados mensuales-->
             <center>
              <div class="grafica" id="1"></div></center>
          <br>
          <!--Grafica metas y resultados semestrales-->
             <center>
              <div class="grafica" id="2">hola</div></center>
          <br>
          <!--Grafica metas y resultados anuales-->
             <center>
              <div class="grafica" id="3">holi anual</div></center>

      </body>
  </html>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#1").show();
      $("#btnmensual").prop('disabled', true);
      $("#2").hide();
      $("#3").hide();
    $("#btnmensual").click(function(){
        $("#1").show();
        $("#2").hide();
        $("#3").hide();
        $("#btnmensual").prop('disabled', true);
        $("#btnsemestral").prop('disabled', false);
        $("#btnanual").prop('disabled', false);
        alertify.success("Haz seleccionado Metas y Resultados Mensuales");
    });
      $("#btnsemestral").click(function(){
        $("#1").hide();
        $("#2").show();
        $("#3").hide();
        $("#btnmensual").prop('disabled', false);
        $("#btnsemestral").prop('disabled', true);
        $("#btnanual").prop('disabled', false);
        alertify.success("Haz seleccionado Metas y Resultados Semestrales");
    });
  });
  </script>
```

Comment: Tendrias que poner el codigo que usas por que va a ser la unica forma de ayudarte

Comment: Hola  Alexis, Lo que se me ocurre es que no se este mapeando correctamente los datos, Serìa una gran ayuda si adjuntas los JSON que le estas enviando para construir la gràficas (Mensual, Semestral, Anual...).

Comment: Dejen edito mi pregunta con el codigo completo Gracias por sus comentarios.

Comment: Alexis, desde tu javascript puede realizar un console.log(data), adentro del método: drawChart3, solo para ver como te esta estructurando los datos para los diferentes casos: Mensual, semestra o anual

Comment: Me podrias explicar mas sobre console.log(data)? asi lo meto tal cual a mi codigo y en consola aparece undefined y si cambio data por drawChart2 que es el que parece mal no se como leer lo que aparece osea solo aparece el mismo codigo.

Answer (score 0):

Que tal chicos ya lo arregle e igual no fue la mejor forma talvez pero eso que importa jaja. Mi Jquery:

```
   <script>

   $(document).ready(function () {
       $("#1").show();

    $("#btnmensual").click(function(){
       $("#1").show();
       $("#2").hide(); 
       $("#3").hide();
    })
    $("#btntrimestral").click(function(){
        $("#1").hide();
        $("#2").show();
        $("#3").hide();
    })
    $("#btnanual").click(function(){
        $("#1").hide();
        $("#2").hide();
        $("#3").show();
    })

   });
</script>
```

Los div donde se muestran las tablas aparecen uno a bajo de otro pero bloqueo el scroll al usuario y solo se muestra la primera entonces si quieres cambiar ahi entra el jquery.

```
<!--Grafica metas y resultados mensuales-->
       <center>
        <div class="grafica" id="1" ></div></center>
    <br>
    <!--Grafica metas y resultados semestrales-->
       <center>
        <div class="grafica" id="2"></div></center>
    <br>
    <!--Grafica metas y resultados anuales-->
       <center>
        <div class="grafica" id="3"></div></center>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La otra posible solucion yo siento que era en la parte superior de cada js en vez de current seria upcoming.
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes
Como dice esto pero pues bueno ya lo solucione espero a alguien le ayude.